# How to use Guava MapInterfaceTest to test your class

Tags: java, unit-testing, guava

I'm trying to test a class that I've written and which implements the Map from Java using Guava-testlib [`MapInterfaceTest`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.guava/guava-testlib/19.0/index.html?com/google/common/collect/testing/MapInterfaceTest.html). When I try and run my MapTest which implements `MapInterfaceTest`, all the tests fail (almost, 52/56) even though all I did was to call the functions from `LinkedHashMap`.

Why is this happening? How does the guava interface test actually work and how can I fix my code? The debugger doesn't really help here.

For example, I have:

```
public void testEqualsForEmptyMap() {
        final Map<K, V> map;
        try {
            map = makeEmptyMap();
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            return;
        }

        assertEquals(map, map);
        assertEquals(makeEmptyMap(), map);
        assertEquals(Collections.emptyMap(), map);
        assertFalse(map.equals(Collections.emptySet()));
        //noinspection ObjectEqualsNull
        assertFalse(map.equals(null));
    }
```

My makeEmptyMap method:

```
@Override
    protected Map<Integer, String> makeEmptyMap() throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        return new MyMap<Integer, String>();
    }
```

My map:

```
private final HashMap<K, V> entries;

public MyMap() {
    entries = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
}
```

This test fails here: `assertEquals(makeEmptyMap(), map);`

Comment: You need to show the code and the test code because otherwise it is not enough to see whcih and why tests are failing.

Comment: MapInterfaceTest isn't something we really use anymore; we almost entirely use MapTestSuiteBuilder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the code visible in your `MyMap` class, the failure is quite normal : as you didn't override the `Object#equals` method, you use the default implementation, which relies upon in-memory equality of references (`Object#equals` is implemented using `==`).

As a consequence, the JVM tries to check if both objects are the same instance in memory, which they aren't. And your test fails.

On a more general note, you have to implement the full interface of `Map` using, sometimes, non trivial code. So unless you exactly known what you do, and why you do it, prefer reusing existing Map implementation.

Comment: You are right. I was missing equals and hashCode. After I generated those 2 methods, all my tests passed

Comment: If you only want to override some methods and delegate all the rest to an existing `Map` implementation, consider using [`ForwardingMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMap.html).